# Oracle SQL developer - problems installing and connecting to ORDS

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

**My Set Up:**
I am running oracle 11g express on my laptop (OS: ubuntu 16.04). I have SQL developer installed and it connects to XE well.

**What I'm trying to do:**
Learn ORDS, first step to which is to get ORDS running via SQL developer.

**What I've done so far:**
I am using the [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/ords/r30/Install_Administer_ORDS/Install_Administer_ORDS.html#section1) guide to install ORDS from within the SQL developer. *I'm connecting to XE (and not ORDS as in step 6)*. The installation completes ok.

**The Problem:**
When I try and connect to the ORDS adminstration using the ords_admin user created earlier in the set up, I get a **HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized** error.

### Connection Properties:

Connection Name: ords_admin
Username:        ords_admin
Hostname:        localhost
Port:            9090
Server Path:     /ords (have also tried /xe out of desperation)

I get the same error when I try and connect to ORDS development with the ords_dev user as well.

Any Ideas on what I am doing wrong or how I can debug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your username or your password are wrong.

No worries, you can just [create a new ORDS user](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2016/10/creating-an-oracle-rest-data-services-user-with-the-sql-developer-role/).

[image]

Or, if you're using SQL Developer version 4.2 or 17.2, you can develop REST services directly from the database instead of connecting over REST to ORDS itself.

Just connect to the schema you've REST enabled, and look at the REST Data Services node in the tree.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you Jeff, that helped! And thanks for the wonderful posts on your website as well.